# SQL: Updating contents of a field by merging 2 fields together

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wondered if anyone could help me with something I am having some issues with.

`TB_SAMPLES` contains a field called Notes.  This field needs to be updated with the contents of my reference table, `SUNCORE_NOTES_UPDATE`.  I need to add this new data as a prefix to any existing notes.

I have been able to select the values as I would like them to be displayed but I am not able to undertake the update.  My 'select' code is below:

```
select traxx_supportb.[jlr_sql].[suncore_notes_update].notes + ' ' +
tb_samples_nw.notes as fullnotes  
from tb_samples_nw, traxx_supportb.[jlr_sql].[suncore_notes_update] 
where tb_samples_nw.id  = traxx_supportb.[jlr_sql].[suncore_notes_update].id
```

Can anyone help me with the SQL required to add the contents to TB_SAMPLES.NOTES from `SUNCORE_NOTES_UPDATE.NOTES` as a prefix?

Thanks very much all!
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
SET notes =  t2.notes + ' ' + t1.notes  
FROM tb_samples_nw t1
JOIN traxx_supportb.[jlr_sql].[suncore_notes_update] t2
ON t1.id  = t2.id
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and the reasoning behind it so others can learn from it.

Comment: @ArtB this is so basic that it should not be necessary

Comment: The are some very very basic users on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an INNER JOIN with an UPDATE.  It also makes it cleaner to alias the tables:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.notes = u.notes 
             + ' '
             + s.notes  
FROM tb_samples_nw s
INNER JOIN traxx_supportb.[jlr_sql].[suncore_notes_update] U
ON S.id  = U.id
```

Be aware that *the original note will be irreversibly modified*, meaning that if you run the query again it will prepend the note again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update tb_samples_nw set notes = IsNull(suncore_notes_update.notes,'')+' '+IsNull(notes,'')
from traxx_supportb.[jlr_sql].[suncore_notes_update]
where tb_samples_nw.id  = traxx_supportb.[jlr_sql].[suncore_notes_update].id
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this Nir, it worked perfectly after a little alteration:                                                          update tb_samples_nw
set tb_samples_nw.notes = IsNull(suncore_notes_update.notes,'')+' '+IsNull(tb_samples_nw.notes,'')
from traxx_supportb.[jlr_sql].[suncore_notes_update], tb_samples_nw
where tb_samples_nw.id  = traxx_supportb.[jlr_sql].[suncore_notes_update].id

Comment: this is a terrible way to join tables

Comment: @t-clausen.dk How so?

Comment: @NirKornfeld join 10 tables using your syntax, then join 10 tables using my syntax. Then imagine the work at maintaining the script

Comment: @t-clausen.dk although your syntax might be clearer in certain times, the execution plan for both are the same. The question here was a simple update, thus a simple answer. No need to make things complicated for no reason.